# How to determine the 'posts on my behalf' setting for a facebook application via the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Due to a recent [policy change on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/365176053526578) I now need to know the 'posts on my behalf' setting the user has my application set to but I can't seem to figure out how to query this parameter.  Here is the setting I'm talking about under 'App Settings':

https://img.skitch.com/20120404-mye28nbkn8f3w4kkfsbb6unb1p.jpg

Is there a way to get what this is set to?  I already checked out me/permissions and its not in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the get it from 'privacy_setting' via FQL as documented on:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/