# Permission issue when uploading photo to album with privacy setting as "Friends of Friends"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to upload photos to photo albums on Facebook from my iOS app. However, I found that when the privacy setting of the photo album is set to "Friends of Friends", upload fails with OAuthException, message as follows:

```
Application's Activity Privacy for User is not sufficient to perform this action
```

I have tried with practically all the permissions specified in [this Facebook developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), but still no success. Uploading works fine when the album privacy settings are the usual such as "Friends", "Only Me" etc so I believe the problem must be due to certain additional permissions required.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this [Bug Report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/365176053526578) in Facebook Developers site. Problem was due to the app's privacy setting being more restrictive than that of the album.

May also want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002941/how-to-determine-the-posts-on-my-behalf-setting-for-a-facebook-application-via).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this error message. I think it happend because I had previously published photos without specifying an album which had created a "default" album named after the app. Worked again once I had created an album explicitly and specified it when uploading the photo.

Comment: Oh it's different from my PixUploader app because in my app the user explicitly select the album they want to upload to. Found that the 'can_upload' field for an album gives an indication whether my app is able to upload to that folder.

Comment: Hmm i should probably take look if there is any difference between a album created by and an app and by a user manually. But for your app at least it seams to work fine for users where the app have created an album explicitly. In an older version we did not create an album, an currently we dont specify and album for those legacy users when uploading a photo... which seams to fail now.