# FQL query for getting users based on app visibility setting

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have found queries which tell which of your friends are using an app:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1
```

However, say you have an application that is more private and the user has the visiblity of that app set to 'Only Me'. Is it possible to to get friends using the app excluding those that want to remain hidden?

I've looked at the permissions table but as far as I can tell none of the permissions are related the 'Visibility of app' setting.

As a side note, if you set the 'Visibility of app' setting to 'Only Me' your photo will not be shown in the app authentication screen when someone else is signing up for the app. So it seems like this behavior exists.

Is there a better 'user friendly' way to replicate this type of behavior?

Comment: Looks like I found a solution after all. 'Visibility of app' was formally known as 'Post on my behalf' and there is a query to get a user's setting:



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002941/how-to-determine-the-posts-on-my-behalf-setting-for-a-facebook-application-via